# Pandas округляет не по правилам математики

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Неожиданно для себя столкнулся с не математическим округлением расчетов.

Простой пример

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[166,34,12,56],
               'b': [27.9625,24.6825,32.738,45.344]})

print df
print (df['a']*df['b'])
print (df['a']*df['b']).round(2)
```

на выходе я получаю:

```
     a        b
0  166  27.9625
1   34  24.6825
2   12  32.7380
3   56  45.3440
0    4641.775
1     839.205
2     392.856
3    2539.264
dtype: float64
0    4641.77
1     839.20
2     392.86
3    2539.26
dtype: float64
```

Как видно из примера числа с 5 округляются в меньшую сторону, а остальное округляется правильно.
И вот мой вопрос, как можно округлять результаты расчетов математически?

У меня версия pandas u'0.23.4',
версия python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 23:32:55)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы округлять `Numpy array` или `Pandas Series` по правилам математики:

```
In [175]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[-0.08, -0.05, -0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.15, 0.25]})

In [176]: df
Out[176]:
      a
0 -0.08
1 -0.05
2 -0.03
3  0.04
4  0.05
5  0.06
6  0.15
7  0.25

In [177]: def my_round(num, n):
     ...:     x = num * 10**n
     ...:     d = x - x.astype('int')
     ...:     return np.where((d>=0.5) | ((d>-0.5) & (d <=0)), np.ceil(x), np.floor(x)) / 10**n
     ...:

In [178]: df['round'] = df['a'].round(1)

In [179]: df['my_round'] = my_round(df['a'], 1)

In [180]: df
Out[180]:
      a  round  my_round
0 -0.08   -0.1      -0.1
1 -0.05   -0.0      -0.1
2 -0.03   -0.0      -0.0
3  0.04    0.0       0.0
4  0.05    0.0       0.1
5  0.06    0.1       0.1
6  0.15    0.2       0.2
7  0.25    0.2       0.3
```

Comment: Снова подниму данную тему. Код:
`def my_round(num, n):
    x = num * 10**n
    d = x - x.astype('int')
    print (d)
    print (d>=0.5)
    return np.where((d>=0.5) | ((d>-0.5) & (d <=0)), np.ceil(x), np.floor(x)) / 10**n
p=pd.DataFrame({'a':[100,],'b':[20.59405,],'c_exp':[2059.41,]})
p['c_act_w_r']= p['a']*p['b']
p['c_act']= my_round(p['a']*p['b'] ,2)
print (p)` дает понять, что 0.5>=0.5 это False. Я понимаю, что сие из-за того, что реальное d чуть меньше чем 0.5. Но вопрос возможно ли и такое округлять по правилам математики?

Answer (score 2):

Округление в Pandas / Numpy и в Python вообще делается согласно [стандарту `IEEE_754`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules):

[Из справка для функции `round()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#round):

> if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even
>   choice (so, for example, both `round(0.5)` and `round(-0.5)` are `0`,
>   and `round(1.5)` is `2`).

Примеры:

```
In [127]: round(0.5)
Out[127]: 0

In [128]: round(1.5)
Out[128]: 2

In [129]: round(2.5)
Out[129]: 2
```

Comment: Это понятно, вот только вопрос в том, что мне необходимо округлять именно математически, другие варианты не подходят. Возможно ли это стандартными средствами или придется писать какой нибудь костыль?